# How to recover photos from previous phone?

Tags: photos

My Lumia recently "died" - the battery quit charging and I now have an Android phone. I have accessed my OneDrive files but my pics that have been uploading (somewhere) are not there. There are older pics from my last Lumia but not the most recent. The pics were going somewhere. How do I recover them and from where?

Comment: Does your Lumia have an SD card (You may have to remove the back cover of the phone to see it. What type of Lumia do you have)? If so, chances are you can just pop it into your new phone, or another computer, and get your photos from there. Of course, you should have set the default location for photos to the SD card, not the internal memory.

Comment: Are you sure that they were uploading? I think it's turned off by default, and you may have never set it back up on your new phone.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to recover these photos.  But since the phone battery is done for, it will be a lot more difficult.  But it would not hurt trying these methods.

- Try connecting your phone to pc/mac Via Usb cable.  And try seeing if the device will be able to be discoverable (if the phone turns on).  If it is found, you can open the local files.
- Re-check your OneDrive Picture folder, it could be hidden somewhere in there.
- Let us just say your phone magically turns on, you can use your android device to connect it Via Bluetooth to transfer files.